# how can i install the packages in r properly and correctly using Rstudio app?

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, r-package

I tried to install *"xlsx"* package using **Rstudio**, and i couldn't install it.

I am trying to install my packages using **install.packages("xlsxjars")**.  I already tried doing that from **Tools** window in Rstudio app, and I tried using the **console**.

I am using **Linux (Gnome 17.04)**.  I get this error:

**input**

```
install.packages("xlsxjars")
```

**output**

```
Installing package into ‘/home/aim/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’ 
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)  
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/xlsxjars_0.6.1.tar.gz'  
Error in install.packages : error reading from connection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you get some Errors while installing r packages kind of somthing.so is miising  or  some packages are missing depending on the version of R, you should try this commands because, i had this kind of errors with R 3.0.x in Ubuntu 14.04
so  i upgrade my R version to fix it with the following commands :

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/" »

gpg —keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com —recv-key E084DAB9

gpg -a —export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get —purge remove r-base-core

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y install r-base

sudo apt-get update

now i can install all packages without errors

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with the answer of @kissi salim yahia

Just want to add . When you tape in R

```
install.packages("your_package")
```

you got some dependencies below.

these one may have troubles sometimes. So just need to install them manually from the SHELL like:

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-your_dependencie
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while struggling with that too. Eventually I just gave up as the java in that package was out of date and I would have needed to load older Java up to get it to run. I would suggest `readxl` instead.

A simple intro to the package can be found here: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-tutorial-read-excel-into-r#readxl